# Regex.IsMatch - not achieving match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list for example:

```
Type [data]
Device Type [data]
Pin type [data]
```

I'm trying to only search for Type [data] not Device Type or Pin Type.
Please note [data] text changes depending on list.

my current code:

```
result = Regex.IsMatch(line1, "\\bType\\b");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use the carat ('^') to match the start of the string.

```
Regex.IsMatch(line1, @"^Type (.*)$");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match `Type` only at the beginning of the string, you do not need regular expressions at all: use the `StartsWith` method of `System.String`, like this:

```
if (line1.StartWith("Type ")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you have a list, but not a list of what. Assuming it's a list of strings, you can find all strings starting with "Type" by using LINQ instead:

```
var matches = data.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Type"));
```

If there is at most one single match, and it's guaranteed to be somewhere in the list, you could use this:

```
var matches = data.Single(x => x.StartsWith("Type"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex `\bType\b` will look for occurences of `Type` at the start of the line, the end of the line, and *between* words.

To match the first case you mentioned you can use this Regex:

```
result = Regex.IsMatch(line1, @"^Type\b");
```

Live Demo: http://rubular.com/r/iEiDEhVt5g

Use `^` to look at the beginning of the line. This way, any occurrences of `Type` between words or at the end will not produce a match.